# Scala ++ operator in lists

Tags: list, scala, set

What does the " ++ " operator do on sets and lists?
For example:

```
(row(r) ++ column(c))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look this up in the documentation: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Answer (score 1):

++ combines the contents of two lists. The new list will contain the contents of `row(r)` followed by the contents of `column(c)`

If row(r) has the contents [1, 2] and column(c) has the contents [3, 4], the new list will contain [1, 2, 3, 4]